# Lyapunov exponent for random dynamical system

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider deterministic discrete dynamical system defined as
$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n).$$

Then Lyapunov exponent is defined as

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln(f'(x_i)).$$

I think that I understand main idea why the Lyapunov exponent is defined in this form.

My problem is that I have not deterministic discrete dynamical system but I have random discrete dynamical system.

Consisder very simple random dynamical system of the form
$$X_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
f(X_n) \text{ with prob. } p,\\
g(X_n) \text{ with prob. } 1-p.
\end{cases}
$$

The question is how the Lyapunov exponent can be define for this random dynamical system (or for random dynamical systems in general). I have been reading somtehing about Lyapunov exponet for sequence of random matrices but I am not sure if it is usable for my problem.

I am studing these things by myself and I am litle bit lost in it. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Not sure but this may help: Random Dynamical Systems, By LUDWIG ARNOLD